# How to skip a directory while searching directories with iteration? (C#)

Tags: c#

I am trying to write an insert query which the data comes from a text file. But the text file is inside a folder. Let me show the hierarchy.

main folder->many folders->many folders->text file also, has another folder named ORJ.

Each of this folder that contains the text file has another folder called ORJ. I don't want to process the orj. Only the text folder and the pdf next to it. How can I do it? I found a code and I am trying to modify it. This is C# by the way.

```
 void ProcessFiles(string path)
{
    Stack<string> stack;
    string[] files;
    string[] directories;
    string dir;

    stack = new Stack();
    stack.Push(path);

    while (stack.Count > 0) {

        // Pop a directory
        dir = stack.Pop();

        files = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
        foreach(string file in files)
        {
            // Process each file
        }

        directories = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);
        foreach(string directory in directories)
        {
            // Push each directory into stack
            stack.Push(directory);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the keyword `continue`

Comment: What an odd way of kind-of-recursion btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a need to do this with a stack?

You could recurse down the tree instead

```
void ProcessFolder(string path) {

    // Process the files 
    foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(path)) {  
        // Process each file  
    }  

    // process the sub folders
   foreach (var subFolder in Directory.GetDirectories(path).Where(fld => System.IO.Path.GetFilename(fld) != "ORJ")) {
        ProcessFolder(subFolder);
    }

}
```

hth,
Alan.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you'd have to check the name of the directory and then just not add it to your stack.

For example:

```
    directories = Directory.GetDirectories(dir);
    foreach(string directory in directories)
    {
        if(directory != "ORJ")             // Push each directory except orj into stack
           stack.Push(directory);
    }
```

Comment: I tried it. It didn't work. The directory equals to c://sth/sth/sth/Orj if nothing helps, I will parse it and write the if.

Comment: @Gece, how about `directory.EndsWith("ORJ")`?

Comment: Then refer to the documentation on how to get the filename(hint).

Comment: Already parsed it, dont know why I even asked it without debugging :) I'll try EndsWith now. Thanks